# Can not establish connection after adding the IP Failover

Tags: networking, freebsd, failover, remote-access

I've bought an dedicated server some days ago, and now its time to setup some more  IP failovers to handle my services, unfortunately, it seems like I can not access certain ports anymore if I'm using the IP failover to connect.

I setup the IP Failover in the following way:

In the `/etc/rc.conf` I've added this line:

`ifconfig_em0_alias0="inet ip.failover netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast ip.failover"`

Lets say the `ip.failover` is `111.222.333.444`, so when I want to connect to the game server on my local machine (port number `7000`) using the above IP failover it is saying that the port `7000` is not reachable on the `111.222.333.444` (the server is binding the IP failover), the strange thing is that, my second server (port number `6000` and normal, original IP there) is working correctly and I can connect to it on my local machine.

Also, I can connect to the `111.222.333.444` failover from my local machine on the SSH port, but others (game ports) seems to be unreachable.

What is wrong? Is that the firewall blocking or what?

My English is not good, so if I'm missing any informations or so, please ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying enough information about your problem, for example you did not specify wheter port 7000 was udp or tcp. You are talking about a firewall but give no clue about his location ( is it on the dedicated server, on your local machine or between).

However, here are two things you can check to solve your problem :

Check that the game server you are running is listening on 111.222.333.444 or * with sockstat -l (it's possible that your game server lists active IP only at startup).

Check that any firewall is allowing you to access that ip adress on the specific port. Do to so, you can use tools like nmap or tcptraceroute... Or you can read the firewall configuration if you have access to it.

Good luck.